# How to solve Empty Result Data Access Exception

Tags: spring-mvc, jdbctemplate, named-parameters

org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0

```
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
@Autowired
public void setJdbcTemplate(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
}
@Override
public UserDetailModel getUserDetail(UserDetailModel detailModel) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
    Map map = new HashMap();
    SqlParameterSource param;
    query.append(" select ");
    query.append(" bu.FIRST_NAME as 'firstname', bu.LAST_NAME as 'lastname', bu.EMAIL as 'email', MOBILE as 'mobile', bu.ID  as 'id', ");
    query.append(" bu.ENABLED as 'enable', bu.IS_ADMIN as 'isadmin', bu.USERNAME as 'username', bu.PASSWORD as 'password' ");
    query.append(" from bamboo_users bu ");
    query.append(" where upper(trim(bu.USERNAME))=upper(trim(:USERNAME)) ");
    query.append(" AND ENABLED='1' ");
    map.put("USERNAME", detailModel.getUsername());
    param = new MapSqlParameterSource(map);
    return (UserDetailModel) jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query.toString(), map, new UserRowMappers());
}
```

Comment: remove  `\n` from the query string

Comment: Nothing Happen.....Same Error display

Comment: I know, that is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

if it is possible to get an empty result, use `queryForList` and only return a value if there is more than one result:

```
List<UserDetailModel> result = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query.toString(), map, new UserRowMappers());
if (result.size>0) {
   return result.get(0)
}
return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the throw keyword, but handle your exceptions yourself.

```
@Override
public UserDetailModel getUserDetail(UserDetailModel detailModel) {
    try {
        ...
        return (UserDetailModel) jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query.toString(), map, new UserRowMappers());

    } catch(Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

1.Print your query to the console to see if the SQL syntax is well-formed.
2.and if you are using client program like workbench, execute using your query.
3.make sure you have data at least one.